# Difference between Web service counter "Current ISAPI Extension Requests" and "ISAPI Extensin Requests/sec"?

Tags: web-server, iis-6, performance-counters

From the Microsoft website, the definition of these two counters is very obscure.

For the "Current ISAPI Extension Requests": 
The current number of ISAPI requests being simultaneously processed by the Web service.
For the "ISAPI Extensin Requests/sec":
The rate that ISAPI Extension requests are received by the Web service.

Sounds resasonable, but what's the exact time of "simultaneously"? millionseconds? or what. 
If we put the simultaneously in the concept of "all requests happened in 1 seconds can be counted as simutaneously", the two counters should have the same results?

On my web server, the Average of "current number of ISAPI requests " is 13; the Average of "ISAPI Extensin Requests/sec" is 110.528, for instance. I can't built any connection between them at all.

Please help me to figure this question if anybody has deeper thoughts about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The definition seems pretty straightforward?

- Requests/Sec = number of requests processed *over a one-second period*
- Requests Current = number of *currently* executing requests (i.e. *at the instant in time at which it's sampled*)

If your ISAPI takes less than a second to process a request, you can squeeze more requests through in a second than are executing at any given point.